# What is the use of the $key in image upload script?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to understand what specifically `$key => $tmp_name` is doing in the following code:

```
if(isset($_FILES['files']))
{
    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name)
    {
        echo $_FILES['files']['name'][$key], "\n";
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, 'img/'.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like it's expecting `tmp_name` to be an array, but PHP re-organises the array if more than one file is uploaded for the same key.

Comment: Is it a multi fileupload script. ie the file element name will be like name="files[]" then the $_FILES will contain array of data

Comment: -1 please read the api for [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and I'm sure things will make sense, perhaps also look into [associative arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) as this is the only type of [array](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) you will find in php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you access your values if you have an upload form that has multiple fields, all named `files[]` or `files[x]` where `x` is a number:

example html:

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" />    // first field
<input type="file" name="files[]" />    // ...
<input type="file" name="files[]" />    // ...
```

The confusing thing is that the sent-in values are not grouped by index, but by their property (`error`, `tmp_name`, etc.).

**Edit:** Based on your edit, I would recommend reading up on [`foreach`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and [`arrays`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) in general.